# Importing Angular bootstrap CSS file

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

Getting 404 error when importing CSS files.

[image]

The path of the css import is perfect and in my local environment, the CSS are loaded but in the production environment, the css don't load.

You can check it out at website: https://demo.openmf.org/newbeta/#/clients

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: The source files were empty which means they were not rendered. Which task runner gulp or grunt you are using

Comment: grunt, if you want to look at the grunt file, here it is: https://github.com/openMF/community-app/blob/new_reskin/Gruntfile.js